# Using Syncthing cli to update its config.xml

Tags: command-line, syncthing

I'm using `syncthing cli` command to update settings in its `config.xml` file.

I have found that it is working only for some parameters, eg `gui.user` and `gui.password`:

```
$ syncthing cli --gui-address=localhost:8384 --gui-apikey=<KEY> config gui user set <VALUE>
$ syncthing cli --gui-address=localhost:8384 --gui-apikey=<KEY> config gui password set <VALUE>
```

But it is failing for almost everything else, eg:

```
$ syncthing cli --gui-address=localhost:8384 --gui-apikey=<KEY> config options minHomeDiskFree set 10
No help topic for 'minHomeDiskFree'
```

Is it possible to update other parameters using `syncthing cli` (and I'm doing something wrong with command syntax) or is there a list of supported parameters for this command (can't find anything in help/man)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `syncthing` like so:

```bash
syncthing cli config options
```

... then it will spit out a rather helpful text explaining how to use the `cli config options` sub-command.

In the text, you will see all the available options, one of these being `min-home-disk-free`.  Note the spelling.

You may then drill further down to discover that you can *get* the currently configured setting like so:

```bash
$ syncthing cli config options min-home-disk-free value get
1
$ syncthing cli config options min-home-disk-free unit get
%
```

This means my currently running `syncthing` instance uses `1%` as the value and unit of the `min-home-disk-free` setting.

You set the value and unit with `set` rather than `get`, followed by the appropriate argument.

```bash
$ syncthing cli config options min-home-disk-free value set 2
$ syncthing cli config options min-home-disk-free value get
2
```